# Strange date result calculating start of next month using NSDateComponents in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I have a function:

```
internal func startOfNextMonth() -> NSDate? {
    guard
        let cal: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar(),
        let comp: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents() else { return nil }
    comp.month = 1
    comp.day = 0
    comp.to12pm()
    let date = cal.dateByAddingComponents(comp, toDate: self.startOfMonth()!, options: [])!
    return date
}
```

This should calculate the first day of next month, however it's returning `2016-03-02 08:00:00 UTC`.

Is this something to do with it being a leap year (Feb. 29 messing it up?)

Here's my `startOfMonth` function for reference, and the `to12pm()` extension:

```
internal func startOfMonth() -> NSDate? {
    guard
        let cal: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar(),
        let comp: NSDateComponents = cal.components([.Year, .Month], fromDate: self.at12pm()!) else { return nil }
    comp.to12pm()
    return cal.dateFromComponents(comp)!
}

internal extension NSDateComponents {
    func to12pm() {
        self.hour = 12
        self.minute = 0
        self.second = 0
    }
}

internal func at12pm() -> NSDate? {
    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    return cal.dateBySettingHour(12, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: self, options: [])
}
```

Comment: 1. Do you want it to return UTC? 2. Post code for `at12pm`.

Comment: 1. I don't particularly care, but all the NSDates I'm using are in UTC, so as long as it's consistent, it shouldn't matter right? 2. Done, whoops. For example, `startOfMonth()` returns `2016-02-01 20:00:00 +0000`.

Comment: Why are you setting the dates to 12pm?

Comment: Because I'm doing several day-based calculations and I want to make sure that the number of days calculated is always consistent.

Comment: You should use NSCalendar method dateByAddingUnit .Month 1

Comment: Maybe I should, but that doesn't explain the behaviour. This was working in January (it returned Feb. 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startOfMonth()` returns first of next month at 12 pm (12:00) then you add another 12 hours in `startOfNextMonth()`, this results one day ahead.

`NSCalendar` has a smart method to calculate the start of next month regardless of daylight saving changes or other irregularity

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.day = 1
let startOfNextMonth = calendar.nextDateAfterDate(NSDate(), matchingComponents: components, options: .MatchNextTime)
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks. That makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to calculate the first day of the next month, all you have to do is:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()
let todayComponents = calendar.components([.Year, .Month], fromDate: NSDate())
todayComponents.month += 1
let firstDayOfMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(todayComponents)
```

Test:

```
print(firstDayOfMonth)
```

Prints in the console:

```
Optional(2016-03-01 08:00:00 +0000)
```

Also, if it is December, the date will overflow to January of the next year.